# how do i change the drag and drop function for a specific drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, drag-and-drop

I would like to change the default drag and drop action for the E:\ drive on my windows 10 machine from copy and paste to move. But I cant find how do do this for just the one drive. I found a way to change the action from move to copy for a single folder using the subst command. Unfortunately thats as close as I have been able to get. Is what I am asking possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default globally, (but not per drive) by modifying the registry.

1. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*`
2. Add or edit the DWORD key `DefaultDropEffect` and set its value to `2`
3. Repeat for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects`

Values:

- `0`:  Perform the default action
- `1`:  Copy by default
- `2`:  Move by default
- `4`:  Always create shortcut

Full discussion of the topic is here: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/38097-drag-drop-default-action-change-windows.html

Comment: Can I change it for internal hard drives only or will it apply to flash drives as well?